# Publishing by showing falsity of existing results

Tags: soft-question

Is it valid to publish a minor result related to computer science complexity theory and classes that disproves and falsifies an existing result?

Would that be a valid and respectable endeavor?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://academia.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

If you respectfully show that an important, i.e., often used/cited, result is false, I think that would be a significant contribution, since obviously those are often the results that have been scrutinized the most and people might build additional work off those results.